# Copy data from excel to another excel by header name

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

I am quite new to python and have difficulty in following issue.

I have 4 excel files. 3 of them are source files and have to be merged using "Customer ID".
4th Excel file (template) is the destination file and has 3 sheets that have to be filled with data from source file.

I could merge the 3 excel files and created one excel file named "all_files"

Now, I do not know how to move data from all_files.xlsx to template.xlsm based on column names.

Here is the columns of all_files:
[all files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co73s.png)
and here is the view of one of the sheets of template: [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9jPp.png)

As you can see, in the template, order of the headers are different (so I cannot use range option) and
headers are in the 3rd row. Could you please help me to find a way to do that?

I have looked at different questions here and could not do anything.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to better understand what you are trying to do. The "all files" image has a "Local customer ID". Is this column common to all of your source files? Why are the column headings in the third row of "template"? Is this desired? Do you want each source file to fill a separate sheet in "template", or do you want all of the source data in one sheet in "template"?

Comment: hello, thanks for your interest. yes, i merged source files using "Local Customer ID" and yes it is desired to have template to start headers in 3rd row. I want to fill a separate sheet. (precisely each individual Customer ID in different template file)

Comment: Just a bit more clarification.... Each individual Customer ID in a separate sheets within the template. Is this correct? The end product will be a single excel file with multiple sheets, each named for a customer ID.